# Run SSRS Report automatically with parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, ssis

I've got about a dozen SSRS reports on various servers which I need to run every month and I would like to run these automatically on the first of each month.  The issue is that the reports require parameters to run like a "start date" and "end date" and a few other parameters.

What would be the best way to go about this?  I've been thinking about creating an SSIS package to do this in C# but just wondering if anyone has any better ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can automate this using [Subscriptions and Delivery Feature in Reporting Service.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159762.aspx)

It allows you to run report at specific time on reporting server. these reports can be delivered to shared folder or to email address.

In the subscription screen in Reporting Services Report manager, go to the options report parameter values, set the reporting parameter values. You can also set default values in reports itself. Let me know more about how do you want to pass the parameter. The start date and end date can be set through expression such as start and end of the month so on.

The parameter value needs to be set such as "start date"  `=DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), "1").AddMonths(-1)` and "end date parameters" `=DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), "1").AddDays(-1)` in the report parameter value section of subscription screen

Comment: Yep, the only thing I don't know how to do with subscriptions is pass parameters.

Comment: In subscription screen in reporting service, go to the options report parameter values, set the reporting parameter values. you can also set default values in reports itself. Let me know more about how do you want to pass the paratmeter. start date and end date can be set through expression such as start and end of the month so on.

Comment: The main set back for me is that each month these reports need to run so I need to go in and change the subscription so the "start date" and "end date parameters" are set to the 1st day and the last day of the previous month respectively.  I would love for this to happen automatically so they run each month all by themselves.

Comment: this is very simple. parameter value needs to be set such as "start date" = =DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), "1").AddMonths(-1)
and   "end date parameters"  = =DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), "1").AddDays(-1) in the report parameter value section of subscription screen.